# How to assert an error being thrown by mocked method using Jest in AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda, jestjs

I have an AWS Lambda function called `getTables` that runs when you hit an API Gateway endpoint.

I would like to mock an exception being thrown by a section of my code that uses de AWS Glue SDK.

How can I properly mock an exception being thrown by a method and how should I assert it?

The test that I have doesn't seem to be working cause I get an unexpected exception which indicates that another part of the code is trying to use the response of the mocked code (meaning it didn't throw?):

```
it('should throw on db not found', async () => {
    mockGetTables.mockReturnValue(new Error("EntityNotFoundException"));
    await getTables(MOCK_REQUEST_EVENT_FAIL, mockContext, mockCallback);
    expect(mockCallback).rejects.toEqual('EntityNotFoundException');
});
```

Here's my Lambda code:

```
export const getTables = async (
  event: APIGatewayProxyEvent,
  _context: Context,
  callback: Callback<APIGatewayProxyResult>
) => {
  console.log('Executing /getTables Activity.');
  console.log(`/getTables event: ${JSON.stringify(event)}.`);

  try {
    const { queryStringParameters } = event;

    let catalogIdParam: string = null;
    let databaseNameParam: string = null;
    let maxResultsParam: number = null;
    let nextTokenParam: string = null;

    if (queryStringParameters) {
      const { catalogId, databaseName, maxResults, nextToken } = queryStringParameters;

      catalogIdParam = catalogId || null;
      databaseNameParam = databaseName || null;
      maxResultsParam = maxResults ? parseInt(maxResults) : null;
      nextTokenParam = nextToken || null;
    }

    const glueClientInstance: GlueClient = GlueClient.getInstance();

    //I'd like to mock the following async method and throw "EntityNotFoundException" 
    //just like API Gateway (or lambda) would do.
    const { TableList, NextToken }: GetTablesResponse = await glueClientInstance.getTables(
      databaseNameParam,
      catalogIdParam,
      maxResultsParam,
      nextTokenParam
    );

    const pandaUITableList: PandaUIGlueTable[] = convertToPandaUITableList(TableList);
    
    callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        TableList: pandaUITableList,
        NextToken,
      }),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`An error ocurred while executing /getTables activity: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);

    if (error.code === 'EntityNotFoundException') {
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          error: error.message,
        }),
      });
    }
    //Generic/CatchAll handler that I'll test later once I figure this one out
    handlerApiError(error, callback);
  }
};
```

For reference, this is the atual error I'm trying to mock and throw:

```
{
    "message": "Database fdv_lin not found.",
    "code": "EntityNotFoundException",
    "time": "2022-03-29T00:47:07.475Z",
    "requestId": "fff5d84c-59de-441d-a204-e08ede830931",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 76.52610613917457
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jest's `toHaveBeenCalledWith()` or `toHaveBeenLastCalledWith()` to assert that the callback is called with the appropriate payload in the catch clause. In this case, it is the below example.

```
callback(null, {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify({
          error: error.message,
        }),
      });
```

**Possible Solution**

```
const mockCallback:Callback<APIGatewayProxyResult> = jest.fn();

it('should throw on db not found', async () => {
mockGetTables.mockReturnValue(new Error('EntityNotFoundException'));
await getTables(MOCK_REQUEST_EVENT_FAIL, mockContext, mockCallback);
expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null, {
  statusCode: 400,
  body: JSON.stringify({
    error: {
      message: 'Database fdv_lin not found.',
      code: 'EntityNotFoundException',
      time: '2022-03-29T00:47:07.475Z',
      requestId: 'fff5d84c-59de-441d-a204-e08ede830931',
      statusCode: 400,
      retryable: false,
      retryDelay: 76.52610613917457,
    },
  }),
});
```

Comment: Yup, I ended up using `toHaveBeenCalledWith()` after a few hours of looking around. But thank you for your answer!